# Improving the preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following strings

```
Football-Europ,
Football-North
Ice_hockey-NHL
Tennis-xxx
```

So I'm using preg_match to the type of the sport and take further step...

```
$sports  = "(football|ice_hockey|basketball|tennis|handball|soccer)"
preg_match($rSports,strtolower($link[1]), $sportType);
```

But I don't need that strings which is including the `Live` and `American` words, how do I have to modify the `preg_match`?

```
Football-Amreican,
Football-Live,
Tennis-Live,
```

Comment: use negative look ahead assertion for the words which you dont want  `$sports  = "(football|ice_hockey|basketball|tennis|handball|soccer)-(?!american|live|nhl)"` where dash - is just added by looking on your examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
"(football|ice_hockey|basketball|tennis|handball|soccer)(?!-(?:Live|American))"
```

It uses a negative lookahead to make sure that the strings are not followed by those words.
Additionally, it will not include the dash (`-`) in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not matching a specific word is hard in regexp. what you need to do is filter the results afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for preg_match_all and a "no case" switch (i):

```
<?php

$rSports =<<<EOF
Football-Europ,
Football-North,
Ice_hockey-NHL,
Tennis-xxx
EOF;

$rSports = trim ($rSports);

# uncomment to use $sports  = "#((football|ice_hockey|basketball|tennis|handball|soccer).*)#i"; // gets you "Football-Europ" etc 
$sports  = "#(football|ice_hockey|basketball|tennis|handball|soccer)#i"; // gets you "Football"
preg_match_all($sports, $rSports, $sportType);

print_r( $sportType);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(^[A-Za-z_]{0,})-
```

this is your pattern